# Can't delete WMA file on my desktop on Windows 8, crashes Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, wmv

I have a WMA file on my desktop that is being stubborn. If I try to delete it, nothing happens. No prompts, no messages, no nothing. If I try to rename it, Windows Explorer crashes and restarts.

I generated the file using Sound Recorder (built-in Windows app). I've tried deleting from command line using `del Untitled.wmv` but command prompt hangs and can't be canceled using Ctrl+C. I tried this while running it as Administrator.

Anyone know why I can't get rid of this file?

Comment: WMV or WMA? Tried deleting it from the command prompt immediately after a reboot, but *without* selecting it first? (Basically reboot, open command prompt and try deleting without otherwise touching the file.) Process Explorer can also be extremely useful to hunt down and close any open file handles, as detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsvistanow/archive/2008/03/12/part-1-using-sysinternals-process-explorer-to-solve-issues-when-trying-to-clean-up-files-and-folders.aspx). If none of this helps you can try running chkdsk to rule out any file system errors.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here...maybe you have a corrupted wmv and windows tb previewer is crashing..
http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/37924-COM-Surrogate-using-50-CPU-non-stop
Hi,

Comment: Welcome to SU! Links can be a helpful addition to an answer for further information, but they should not be the bulk of the answer. Can you summarize the answer found in the link you posted here? You can read more about it here, [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/189763).